# Dispose JFrame from another class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, dispose

How can I dispose JFrame from another class? My code is listed below.
I use Netbeans generate form for generate window. And I want dispose using another class(name is needDispose).

```
    public class needDispose {
         /**
          *Call for dispose frame
          */
        public static void disposeMyFrame(){
            myEasyFrame.getMainFrame.dispose(); // DOESNT WORK
        }
    }
```

**NETBEANS GENERATE**
(important method is getMainFrame() )

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class myEasyFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    /*
     * Get frame
     */
    public final JFrame getMainFrame() {
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Creates new form myEasyFrame
     */
    public myEasyFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("CLICK");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        needDispose.disposeMyFrame();
    }                                        


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(myEasyFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(myEasyFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(myEasyFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(myEasyFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new myEasyFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Logic would be to pass a reference of your JFrame to this other class, and then call the dispose method of the JFrame from that class.

Comment: How? Can you give me a example?

Comment: Alright, but first tell, what does this other class do? I'll write an example in my answer based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to dispose a JFrame from another class which itself is a JFrame:

```
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Demo
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
      @Override
      public void run()
      {
        FrameA one = new FrameA();
        FrameB two = new FrameB(one);

        one.setVisible(true);
        two.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }
}

class FrameA extends JFrame
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1812279930292019387L;

  public FrameA()
  {
    super("Frame A");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(400, 400);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    setResizable(false);
  }
}

class FrameB extends JFrame
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 5126089271972476434L;

  public FrameB(final JFrame otherFrame)
  {
    super("Frame B");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(400, 400);
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    setLocationRelativeTo(otherFrame);

    JButton button = new JButton("Dispose Other");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
        otherFrame.dispose();
      }
    });

    add(button);

    setResizable(false);
  }
}
```